# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency for redux action as parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I found many similar questions here about **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency**. I have already checked them, but I didn't find solutions as I faced. I want to pass **redux thunk function** as a parameter to **React custom hook**.

Below is my code and it is working fine. But, I got dependency missing warning, I don't want to add **ignore warning eslint**. If I add *dispatchAction* to dependency array list, it is dispatching again and again because redux thunk asyn function  has fulfilled, reject, pending.

Custom Hook

```
const useFetchData = (dispatchAction, page) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loadMoreLoading, setLoadMoreLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoadMoreLoading(true);
      const resultAction = await dispatch(dispatchAction);
      if (resultAction.meta.requestStatus === 'rejected') {
        setErrorMsg(resultAction.payload.message);
      }
      setLoadMoreLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  return [loadMoreLoading, errorMsg]; // it is asking for adding dispatchAction.
```

My component

```
const SomeListing = ({userId}) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loadMoreLoading, errorMsg] = useFetchData(
    fetchPropertyByUserId({userId: userId, page: page}),
    page,
  );
}
```

So, is there any way to be able to add **redux thunk function** in react custom hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fetchPropertyByUserId`, when called i.e. `fetchPropertyByUserId({userId: userId, page: page})`, returns an "actionCreator" function.

Hence, when you call this function at the place of first parameter of your hook `useFetchData`, it returns a new "actionCreator" function each time (we know that hooks are called at each render):

In **SomeListing.jsx:**

```
const [loadMoreLoading, errorMsg] = useFetchData(
  fetchPropertyByUserId({userId: userId, page: page}), // <-- Here: it returns a new "actionCreator" function at call (render)
  page,
);
```

And, as soon as you put this function (first parameter of the hook i.e. `dispatchAction`) as a dependency of `useEffect`, it should cause an infinite execution of the effect because, now we know, that `dispatchAction` is getting created (hence, changed) at every render.

In **useFetchData.js:**

```
export const useFetchData = (dispatchAction, page) => {

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoadMoreLoading(true)
      const resultAction = await dispatch(dispatchAction)
      if (resultAction.meta.requestStatus === 'rejected') {
        setErrorMsg(resultAction.payload.message)
      }
      setLoadMoreLoading(false)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [dispatch, dispatchAction, page]) // <-- "dispatchAction" added here

  // ...
```

### How to fix it?

Pass a memoized actionCreator function:

In **SomeListing.jsx:**

```
export const SomeListing = ({ userId }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

  // Here: "fetchPropertyByUserIdMemo" is memoized now
  const fetchPropertyByUserIdMemo = useMemo(
    () => fetchPropertyByUserId({ userId: userId, page: page }),
    [page, userId]
  )

  const [loadMoreLoading, errorMsg] = useFetchData(fetchPropertyByUserIdMemo, page)

  // ...
}
```

Comment: well explanation

Answer (score -1):

How about extracting the fetch method from useEffect?:

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoadMoreLoading(true);
    const resultAction = await dispatch(dispatchAction);
    if (resultAction.meta.requestStatus === 'rejected') {
      setErrorMsg(resultAction.payload.message);
    }
    setLoadMoreLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {  
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);
```

Comment: I think you miss this thread, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920